# Solubility of n-butanol and n-butanamine

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility

I ran across something saying that n-butanamine is miscible in water while butanol is only partially soluble. Is this correct? Can anyone offer an explanation? I would have guessed that the decreased polarity of the amine relative to the alcohol would have resulted in lower solubility for n-butanamine.

Comment: An amine has two hydrogens attached to an electronegative atom and so can form more hydrogen bonds with water than an alcohol. I think this is correct but I have no source.

Comment: It is the basicity of the amine that makes the difference.

Comment: [For nButanol](https://srdata.nist.gov/solubility/IUPAC/SDS-15/SDS-15.pdf) --

[Theorical solubility for nButylamine](https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB03659) --

[PubChem value for nButylamine](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Butylamine#section=Computed-Properties)

Answer (score -7):

Out of butanamine and butanol, butanol is more soluble in water due to higher electronegativity of oxygen . And as butanol  have more polar oxygen so it will be more attracted towards water and form H bond.so it is soluble but amine are miscible due to enthalpies that will release out because of electron donating nature of nitrogen.